# Convert a full wordpress site to HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I'm trying to get a wordpress site to HTTPS, but everything I try gives me a redirect loop. I've edited the htaccess, I've set it in PHP, I've even downloaded a wordpress plugin to convert it, but every method gives me a redirect loop error. I know that something has to be redirecting my https to http, but I don't know what. Here is my .htaccess file without any of the HTTPS settings in it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And here's the PHP I'm trying to use in the header php file to conver the page to HTTPS:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a blanket redirect in .htaccess or in PHP. Go to Dashboard >> Settings and change your URLs to https. Then save permalinks.

You may want to find/replace any http URLs in post/page content, media URLs, etc, so you don't get redirects for those from http to https. Try [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

After https is working, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if you are getting any "insecure content" errors from non-https URLs in any theme files.

You may need to change to a relative path for images in CSS files, i.e. `background-image: url(http://example.com/themes/wp-content/theme/images/image.jpg)` to `background-image: url(images/image.jpg)`

And, you may need to remove the `http` from absolute paths in php theme files, i.e. change `'http://example.com/image.jpg'` to `'//example.com/image.jpg'`; that will allow your resources to default to https.

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't change anything. It's still on http, even when I change the settings. Even if I manually add the https in the URL bar, it goes back to normal http.

Comment: Do you have an SSL installed at the webhost? Are there https to https redirects at the host? Have you checked theme files for redirects that are breaking your attempts?

Comment: I have an SSL cert, the checkout page in Woocommerce loads over HTTPS. What should I be looking for in theme files that might be breaking the redirect?

Comment: Look at http://docs.woothemes.com/document/ssl-and-https/ for The Force SSL setting

Comment: Okay, so, it looks like the "Force HTTPS on checkout" in woocommerce also comes with a "...and nowhere else" button. Unticked that and the wordpress-https plugin started working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to general settings and change WordPress Address from http to https

Here is more tweaks https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/

You also may try this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

Comment: Changing the address doesn't work, it still loads over http. Wordpress-https doesn't change anything either.